# How to configure kibana for elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Currently from my application server (linux) the below is the format of the command that I use to connect to Elastic search which runs on a different server (linux) using curl

```
curl --cacert certs/ca.crt --user elastic:password -X GET "https://elastic-server.env.domain.business.com:19200/_cat/indices?pretty=true"
```

Note: that **ca.crt** is present within the **certs** directory path

If I am installing Kibana on a different server(linux) than the ones that the Elastic search is running on (linux server) how should I configure the **kibana.yml**
to include the ca.crt for all the requests that Kibana makes because without a valid certificate in the request the Elastic search will not respond.

Answer (score 0):

which documentation you use and what version you're running? because the official Doc treats this use case

you can check the link [Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup-https.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).